# How to open colorbox inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

Actually i want to do open color box without popup and it need to be only show hide inside a div. can we target a div to open colorbox content.

```
<a href='#myGallery' class='group'>click here</a>

<div class=''><!--this must be container of colorbox, and disable popup--> 
    <div id="myGallery"><--some content with photo--></div>
</div>


function _teamPopup(){
   $(".group").colorbox({
     inline:true, 
     rel:'group',
     href:$(this).attr('href'),
     scrolling: false,
     opacity:1,
     width:100+"%",

   });
}
```

on my web page , there is lot of thumbnails, when i click on it content must display without popup.and it can be next ,prev , close like colorbox group function.

please check below image and you can get some idea.
[image]

Comment: where is javascript/colorbox code?

Comment: @ManProgrammer updated.. can you please check it.

Comment: could you please paste your code on fiddle it is easy to us for solving your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use toggle function of jQuery to hide and show content inside an element

Comment: my question is updated and now you can understand what i am trying to say. can you please check it again.

Comment: So you want to show content without changing the alignment of thumbnails beside as shown above?

Comment: And while showing content of one thumbnail, other thumbnails should be accessible? If yes, its better to realign other thumbnails by moving them further. If no, try to make content div position absolute and place it beside thumbnail clicked and give top and left to content div by getting position of thumbnail like $(thumbnail).position().

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to change colorbox if its purpose is exactly to have a gallery popping up?

If you look around there are widgets more specific for the kind of problem you're having.

Check http://galleria.io/themes/classic/.

If you still don't like what you can find around why don't you just code the big div to change its image when clicking on a thumbnail?